# Insert 'Enter Keypress' using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a quote function, which is when user click on 'QUOTE' for that text (eg:"This is my text"), in my textarea will display "> This is my text". and user can add their text below that text. Currently, after i quote, then click on textarea, my cursor is at the new line, but when i add the textarea, my quote text and text enter is in one line

Here my HTML

```
<span style='float:left' id="topmod"></span><br/>
<textarea class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name='modrepmsg' id='modrepmsg' cols='100' rows='8' tabindex='1004'></textarea><br/>
<br/>
<span id="modquote" style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;">QUOTE</span>
<input type="hidden" name="repmsg" id="repmsg" />
<span id="modadd" class="button_form" style="cursor:pointer;"><?php echo $lang['REQUEST_ADD_B']; ?></span>
```

Here my Jquery for quote

```
$( '#modquote')
  .click(function() {
    var comment = $('#repmsg').val();
    var quote = ">" + comment + "\n";

    $('textarea#modrepmsg').html(quote);
});
```

Here my jquery for save

```
    $( '#modadd')
  .click(function() {
    var repmsg = $('#modrepmsg').val();

    window.location = 'reply_msg.php?msg=' + repmsg;
});
```

In my reply_mg.php i request the msg `$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];`

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)???

Comment: @EmilioGort no i don't since i really new in programming. thanks

Answer (score 0):

tray this:

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) { // get Enter key
      // your code here
   }
});
```

Comment: In this case try this approach:
`$('body').on('keypress','#textbox',function(){ /* code here */ });`